# Understanding of a float counter

Tags: java

I have following simple code:

```
for (float i=0; i<1f; i+=0.1) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I have just got following results:

```
0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.70000005
0.8000001
0.9000001
```

But I can't understand why there is. Please, I hope you can tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Let's say this: you read [OMG Ponies!!! (Aka Humanity: Epic Fail)](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) and then return here, ok? :-)

Comment: Looks like a precision issue.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713673/precision-error-with-floats-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/):

> **Why don’t my numbers, like 0.1 + 0.2 add up to a nice round 0.3, and
>   instead I get a weird result like 0.30000000000000004?**
>
> Because internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point)
>   that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all.
>
> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

Comment: This. Use an integer for counters. Also, due to this floating point issue, you can never trust a floating point to be == to another floating point. Use some sort of precision error (0.000045)? to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

Well because with the way float has been implemented there usually is a very small deviation from the mathematical 0.1f you are incrementing with, so actually you are incrementing with just a small amount over that.

A solution would be to use:

```
BigDecimal
```

EDIT:

Michael posted a better description of your problem, but still you should take a look at BigDecimal.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the way computers store floating point numbers.
For detailed information you could have a look at the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

This is related to a numerical problem.

Answer (score 0):

You almost always need to constrain the number of decimal places when printing floats or doubles.

Java's take on printf from C

```
for (float i = 0; i < 1f; i += 0.1) {
    System.out.printf("%.1f\n", i);
}
```

DecimalFormat to print up to 1 decimal place if necessary

```
DecimalFormat format1 = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
for (float i = 0; i < 1f; i += 0.1) {
    System.out.println(format1.format(i));
}
```

DecimalFormat to print 1 decimal place always

```
DecimalFormat format2 = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
for (float i = 0; i < 1f; i += 0.1) {
    System.out.println(format2.format(i));
}
```