# Java, Float.parseFloat(), System.out.printf() inconsistency

Tags: java

Consider the following code in Java :

```
String input = "33.3";
float num = Float.parseFloat(input);  
System.out.printf("num: %f\n",num);
```

Why is the output of the code above

`num: 33.299999`     ?

Shouldn't it be

`num: 33.300000`     ?

I would really appreciate it if someone can explain this to me.

Comment: Floating point precision. Check out http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6713673/1053938

Answer (score 7):

You're a victim of floating-point error. In base 2, `33.3` is technically a repeating binary(similar to a repeating decimal), as when written as `m/n` with `m` and `n` being integers and `gcd(m,n)=1`, the prime factors of `n` are not a subset of the prime factors of 2. This also means that it cannot be written as the sum of a finite number of terms `m*(2^n)` where `m` and `n` are integers.

A similar example happens with `7/6` in base 10.

```
   _
1.16
```

becomes

```
1.16666667
```

which is then read literally, and is not equal to 7/6.

Comment: In binary there is no decimal point, only a binary point, so it's a repeating *binary* (not a repeating *decimal*)

Comment: @Bohemian You're right, I should use the semantically correct term.

Comment: @Bohemian Even 0.1 is a repeating binary as it is not a simple sum of powers of 2.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sure. My comment was more about terminology. If in the decimal system we have a decimal point and decimal places, in the binary system we must have a binary point and binary places, etc.

Comment: @Bohemian I agree with you, but it comes as a surprise to some that 0.1 is not represented exactly but as a rounded repeating binary.

Comment: @hexafraction, If I change the code to

    String input = "3.33";
    float num = Float.parseFloat(input);  
    System.out.printf("num: %f\n",num);  

Then why is the output OK? i.e:

    num = 3.330000

Comment: @Froggy Change it to what? There's no Java non-integer type that will let you do this without rounding error.

Comment: @Froggy It's not OK. It's still truncated, and there are stray non-zero characters beyond the printing cutoff.

Comment: @hexafraction num is printed to be the original number as-is 3.330000 instead of 3.299999 which I consider OK.

Comment: @Froggy Only by coincidence that the truncated value is over the actual in this case. It's 50% hit or miss.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `float` if you can avoid it.  The problem here is that `%f` is treating it as a double when it doesn't have that precision

```
String input = "33.3";
double num = Double.parseDouble(input);
System.out.printf("num: %f\n",num);
```

prints

```
33.300000
```

This occurs because 33.3f != 33.3 as `float` has less precision.  To see the actual values you can use BigDecimal which covers the actual value precisely.

```
System.out.println("33.3f = " + new BigDecimal(33.3f));
System.out.println("33.3 = " + new BigDecimal(33.3));
```

prints

```
33.3f = 33.299999237060546875
33.3 = 33.2999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875
```

As you can see the true value represented is slightly too small in both cases.  In the case of how `%f` it shows 6 decimal places even though float is not accurate to 8 decimal places in total.  `double` is accurate to 15-16 decimal places and so you won't see an error unless the value is much larger. e.g. one trillion or more.

Comment: Problem is, technically even _that_'s not exactly 33.3, which is not representable in any binary floating-point system.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Except perhaps one that uses 2 fixed-precision integers akin to a rational number.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young But when you print it, it will round it to the correct value.

Comment: @hexafraction (Misread your comment, sorry.) Yes, you can create a rational type, and it'd indeed work. In fact, some programming languages have built-in rationals. <3

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Something which Java needs somewhat desperately. I'd love to see programmer-defined primitives, even if they required JNI to be implemented.

Comment: @hexafraction or perhaps the writers of the `Double.toString(double)` knew what they were doing ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simply that float has finite precision.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit floating point numbers contain enough precision for about 7 decimal places of accuracy.
33.29999 is 7 decimal places.
Change "input" to be 3.3 -- you should see 3.300000
Change "input" to be 333.3 -- you will see something like :333.299988
Using a 64-bit floating point number will give you more precision (15-17 decimal places).