# Why does Java return the wrong result of subtraction?

Tags: java

What result will I get if from 2.49 I take 0.17 ? 
2.32 of course !!!
But why the Java return 2.3200000000000003 ?

This is my easy code:

```
    double x = 2.49;
    double y = 0.17;

    System.out.println(x - y);
```

How can I get the right result ?

Comment: I think this duplicate is a better fit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: And also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Found this other duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713673/precision-error-with-floats-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
  double d = x-y;
  DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
  System.out.println(f.format(d));
```