# How to convert a String ("95941634.164") to a float

Tags: java

When I tyr to convert a String "95941634.164" to a float and print the same, it is printing as 9.5941632E7 but not as 95941634.164.

I tried following conversion methods Float.parseFloat() and Float.valueOf()

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s = "95941634.164" ;
    Float f  = Float.valueOf(s);
    System.out.println(f);
    System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("95941634.164"));
}
```

Actual: 9.5941632E7 expected 95941634.164

Comment: Hi anil, you might want to look at this existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713673/precision-error-with-floats-in-java . Some languages are notorious for their precision on Floats.

Comment: If you want to keep the accuracy you should use BigDecimal: BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("95941634.164");

Answer (score 4):

The nearest `Float` to `95941634.164` is `95941632`.

And Java is using scientific notation to output that value.

Given that the nearest `Double` to your number is `95941634.1640000045299530029296875`, you might have more tractable output if you use a `Double`. But if you want exact decimal results then use a decimal type: `BigDecimal` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try String.format with cast to double. Here is an example :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String s = "95941634.164" ;
    Float f= Float.parseFloat(s);
    Double d  = Double.parseDouble(s);
    System.out.println(String.format("%.3f", f));
    System.out.println(String.format("%.3f", d));
}
```

The format rounds off while using float but not for double.
Here is the output :

```
95941632.000                                                                                                                            
95941634.164
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use printf() with %f:

```
System.out.printf("value: %f\n", f);
```

Comment: the problem is not here, the problem is the number of bits in the mantissa of a _float_