# How can I get the first 5 numbers of a double

Tags: java, math, double

how can i only have the first 5 numbers in a double?

```
12345.6789 --> 12345
1.23456789 --> 1.2345
0.123456789 --> 0.1234
```

I have tried different things such as multiplying the number by the power of 10 and x
but x seems to only affect the decimal places, setting it to x decimal places

Comment: What do you want to do with these values? If you just want to print them, convert to a `String` and take the first 5 chars (or six if there is a decimal point).

Comment: What is the **type** of the result you want to have? Basically, you can only get there when turning to a STRING representation, as floating point numbers have inherent issues about representation

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713673/how-can-i-handle-precision-error-with-float-in-java just for example.

Comment: What does this have to do with math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up going with the following:

```
//cuts the string to the first 6 letters
String sixLetter = aDouble.toString().substring(0,6);

//checks if there is a "." before the 5th character so we don't end up with 12345.
if (sixLetter.indexOf(".") > 4) {
//then assuming there is not a "." it will cut it to the first 5 characters

    return sixLetter.substring(0,5);
//if there is a "." (other than 12345.) it will cut it down to 5 characters resulting in 12345
};
return sixLetter;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Using `BigDecimal`:

- move the decimal point to the right/left until only the desired number of (significant) digits are in front of the decimal point;
- set the scale to zero, that is, removed all digits after the decimal point or extend the precision up to the point (if missing digits);
- move the decimal point back to where it was, undoing first step.

```java
static BigDecimal convert(BigDecimal number, int significant) {
    var beforeDecimal = number.precision() - number.scale();
    var movePoint = significant - beforeDecimal;
    return number
           .movePointRight(movePoint)
           .setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN)
           .movePointLeft(movePoint);
}
```

called like
`convert(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.23456789), 5)`
or
`convert(new BigDecimal("1.23456789"), 5)`

to return the BigDecimal:
`1.2345`

Answer (score 0):

As others commented, one way to do this is with string manipulation. May not seem elegant, but it gets the job done.

Define some inputs.

```java
double[] doubles = { 12345.6789 , 1.23456789 , 0.123456789 } ;
```

Loop those inputs. For each one, generate a string. If a FULL STOP is found, take first *six* characters. If not, *five*. If the FULL STOP lands in the last place, such as in our first example input, delete.

```java
for( double d : doubles )
{
    String s = String.valueOf( d ) ; 
    String s5 = s.substring( 0 , s.contains( "." ) ? 6 : 5 ) ;
    if( s5.endsWith( "." ) ) { s5 = s5.substring( 0 , s5.length() - 1 ) ; }  // Drop FULL STOP in last place.
    System.out.println( s5 ) ;
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jcMnzY).

```
12345
1.2345
0.1234
```

Caveat: You may need to internationalize by accounting for a COMMA (`,`) as the [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator) rather than a FULL STOP (`.`) character.

```
String s5 = s.substring( 0 , ( s.contains( "." ) || s.contains( "," ) ) ? 6 : 5 ) ;
```

Comment: Perhaps "may not seem elegant" is synonymous with "reinventing the wheel" in that case ;-) I'm not very familiar with Java, but surely there is a simpler solution using [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) or [java.text.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) or [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

- convert to a string.
- check for a decimal.
- if not present (= -1) or >= 5, set i to 5. Else set to 6
- then get the substring from 0 to i.

```
double[] v = {12345.6789,
1.23456789,
0.123456789};

for (double d : v) {
    String s = Double.toString(d);
    int i = s.indexOf('.');
    i = i < 0 || i >= 5 ? 5 : 6;
    System.out.println(s.substring(0,i));
}
```

prints

```
12345
1.2345
0.1234
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Java, but surely there is a simpler solution using [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) or [java.text.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Format.html) or [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)?

Comment: As far as I know the problem lies with the decimal point which adds some complexity.  Most formats work on field widths regardless of the decimal point.  So it would be easier to print something like `12345, 1.234, 0.123`.  where the fields are of width 5.  But this isn't what you apparently wanted.

Comment: If the number is >= 10000 then there won't be a decimal point. If the number is < 10000 then there will be a decimal point. I think it's that simple?

Comment: One must also consider automatic rounding to avoid `12345.678` from printing as `12346`.